# Appending data to JSON file in C

Tags: c

I have this code which I use to append data to a JSON file. It will be helpful if someone could suggest pointers on:

- Reducing file opening and closing
- Make the `write_json` function efficient

and other general pointers. Thanks a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ENTRIES_PER_LOG 10000

static int packet_count = 0;
static char filename[100] = "output.json";

int write_json(const char *json){
    packet_count++;
    // create file if it doesn't exist
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
       fp = fopen(filename, "w");
       if (!fp)
           return 0;
       fputs("[]", fp);
       fclose(fp);
    }

    // add the document to the file
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (fp)
    {
       // check if first is [
       fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
       if (getc(fp) != '[')
       {
           fclose(fp);
          return 0;
       }

       // is array empty?
       int is_empty = 0;
       if (getc(fp) == ']')
           is_empty = 1;

      // check if last is ]
       fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
       if (getc(fp) != ']')
       {
           fclose(fp);
           return 0;
       }


       // replace ] by ,
       fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
       if (!is_empty)
           fputc(',', fp);

       // append the document
       fputs(json, fp);

       // close the array
       fputc(']', fp);
       fclose(fp);
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        char json[100] = "";
        sprintf(json, "{\"a\":%d}", packet_count);
        write_json(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you `printf`-ing your entire output?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. You first open the file for reading. If this succeeds, the next thing you do (without closing the file) is another fopen with a different mode.  I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by doing this, but it doesn't look like it makes sense.
2. I *think* that you are trying to see whether the file exists, create it if it doesn't, and then open it so you can read and write.  If I understand you correctly, then mode "a+b" opens the file for reading and writing.  It appends if the file exists; it does not delete the contents. This should be sufficient.
3. JSON is a text file.  I am not sure why you are opening it in binary mode.  I would expect to see "a+"
4. I'm pretty sure there are working libraries to handle reading and writing JSON files from a C program...you might try searching for one

I am out of time; if I have time tomorrow night I will try to see if I can refine this or add more thoughts.